# Silverlight 3 - Exchange Web Service

Tags: silverlight, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In my Silverlight 3 app, I just added a Service Reference to the Exchange 2007 Web Service (EWS). After doing so, I got the following warning:

> Custom tool warning: No endpoints
>   compatible with Silverlight 3 were
>   found. The generated client class will
>   not be usable unless endpoint
>   information is provided via the
>   constructor.

As a result, I can't use the ExchangeServiceBinding from the Silverlight code (which seems like the key class to use to make calls to the service). Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silverlight supports only Basic Http Binding at the moment.  So, what you need to do is that create a web service that wrap the EWS and enable the Basic Http Binding of your webserivce.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was going to be the way to go, but I wanted to run it by people before going down that path. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more that how i can wrap EWS service in my silverlight app